# Reminder of, or reminder on?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions

I am not a native English speaker, but as a mathematician (well, PhD student in mathematics) I need to write daily in this language. Sometimes, I have doubts about the correct formulation of certain sentences, and as I tend to be a perfectionist, this makes me waste a lot of time on research on the web. Sometimes, however, I am not able to find what I am looking for. This is one of these times.

A section of an article I am writing is dedicated to notions already well-known in the literature, and in particular to a theorem called the Homotopy Transfer Theorem. I want to make this explicit in the title of the section, thus I named it

> Reminder **of** the Homotopy Transfer Theorem.

However my advisor (who is also not a native English speaker) told me that I should write

> Reminder **on** the Homotopy Transfer Theorem.

As already mentioned, I looked online but my research was not conclusive. For example, in [this discussion in a forum](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/reminder-on-reminder-of.2916715/) they say that it is a matter of "what sounds better". Does anyone have a rule on which one to use - *of*, or *on* - or, if both are correct, an opinion on which one sounds better in this case?

Comment: PS: I am not sure if I tagged the question correctly. If you have suggestions for further or different tags, feel free to tell me or to directly edit the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A reminder *of* the theorem can mean just reminding people that it exists.

A reminder *on* the theorem or (**better**) a reminder ***about*** the theorem means that the reminder includes some **information about the theorem**.

Answer (score 1):

Reminder of.

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/reminder

Examples:

‘As the room emptied out at the end of the hearing, they remained the only physical **reminders of** the traumatic testimony that had expired.’

‘The sound of nearby gunfire interrupts the inspection, a stark **reminder of** the dangers never far away.’

‘The walls remain, a purposeful **reminder of** the waste of war, and the roofless interior become a sort of peace park for contemplation.’

‘His faced loomed before her, a bittersweet **reminder of** her past.’

‘They probably served as visual **reminders of** wartime experiences - either as private memories or collective talking points for survivors.’

‘The film is a poignant **reminder of** the reasons to live - love, laughter, vibrancy.’